# Site url exceeds maximum length of 256

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, team-sites

I'm trying to create a team site and get the following error message

> Site url https://myurl/sites/mylongsitename exceeds maximum length of 256.

The url itself is under the 256 limit, I've also tried appending "Shared Documents" and "Shared%20Documents" and its still under the limit. Does anything else get appended to increase the length.

Is there a way for me to validate this before attempting to create it?

This is the code I am using [source](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/create-site-collections-with-csom-in.html?m=1)

```
 using (ClientContext tenantContext = new ClientContext("https://yoursite-admin.sharepoint.com/"))
        {
            //Authenticate with a Tenant Administrator
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            tenantContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

            var tenant = new Tenant(tenantContext);

            //Properties of the New SiteCollection
            var siteCreationProperties = new SiteCreationProperties();

            //New SiteCollection Url
            siteCreationProperties.Url = "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/codesite";

            //Title of the Root Site
            siteCreationProperties.Title = "Site Created from Code";

            //Email of Owner
            siteCreationProperties.Owner = "admin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com";

            //Template of the Root Site. Using Team Site for now.
            siteCreationProperties.Template = "STS#0";

            //Storage Limit in MB
            siteCreationProperties.StorageMaximumLevel = 100;

            //UserCode Resource Points Allowed
            siteCreationProperties.UserCodeMaximumLevel = 50;

            //Create the SiteCollection
            SpoOperation spo = tenant.CreateSite(siteCreationProperties);

            tenantContext.Load(tenant);

            //We will need the IsComplete property to check if the provisioning of the Site Collection is complete.
            tenantContext.Load(spo, i => i.IsComplete);

            tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //Check if provisioning of the SiteCollection is complete.
            while (!spo.IsComplete)
            {
                //Wait for 30 seconds and then try again
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                spo.RefreshLoad();
                tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("SiteCollection Created.");

        }
```

The total length of the url is 148

Comment: mpore information required. what are the exact length of the url? how you trying to create the site?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Don't you have any zone (alternate access mapping, AAM) that has a URL that may cause exceeding the limitation?

Comment: Not that I know of. How do I find out?

Comment: Central Administration / Application Management / Configure alternate access mappings (Web Applications)

Comment: I cant see this option in SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved this, well from the tests I have done.

It appears if the url is greater than 136 characters you will get this error.

http://tenant/sites/mysitename "This can not be great than 136 characters"

I've tried this on two different tenants

- tenant 1 - https://tenant1/ 32 chars
- tenant 2 - https://tenant2/ 33 chars
- tenant 1 - site name = 97 chars
- tenant 2 - site name = 96 chars

you also have to factor in "sites" - "teams".

This is the only way I can see of validating a site collection. If I'm wrong please let me know.

I've updated this post with a screen shot. The highlighted textbox has a dynamic max length.

[image: Site Collection Creation Screen Shot]

Comment: Strange. These numbers seem not to correspond to the values officially published at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919564.aspx.

Comment: I'm only going on what I have tested. Unless any additional validation is done on the server before creation. Maybe something else is appended on to the end of a site address ie Shared Documents/All.aspx. I'm open to any other suggestions. Even with appending the above I'm still within the limit.